# Typescript + my NPM package: Could not find a declaration file for module

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

I have a React component library that I import using NPM and I'm trying to convert it to Typescript.

```
import React from 'react';
import SvgIcon from '@myapp/ui/components/SvgIcon'; //<---------------- not working

function App() {
  return (
    <SvgIcon />
  );
}

export default App;
```

However, Typescript keeps complaining that I do not have the declarations:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module '@myapp/ui/components/SvgIcon'. '/Users/edmundmai/Documents/my-app/node_modules/@myapp/ui/components/SvgIcon.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/myapp__ui` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module '@myapp/ui/components/SvgIcon';`
```

But when I open up node_modules, it looks like my library is setup fine?

[image]

`node_modules/myapp/ui/package.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "main": "./index.js",
  "types": "./index.d.ts",
}
```

`node_modules/@myapp/ui/index.js`:

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });

var components_SvgIcon = require('./components/SvgIcon.js');
require('./tslib.es6-46449784.js');
require('react');
require('styled-components');
require('./constants/properties.js');



exports.SvgIcon = components_SvgIcon["default"];
```

`node_modules/@myapp/ui/index.d.ts`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { SVG_ICON_COLORS, SVG_ICON_SIZES } from './constants/properties';

interface Props {
    icon: React.FC<React.SVGAttributes<SVGSVGElement> & React.ImgHTMLAttributes<SVGSVGElement>>;
    stroke?: SVG_ICON_COLORS;
    fill?: SVG_ICON_COLORS;
    size?: SVG_ICON_SIZES;
    alt_text?: string;
    className?: string;
}
declare const SvgIcon: ({ stroke, fill, size, icon: Icon, className, alt_text, }: Props) => JSX.Element;

export { SvgIcon };
```

`node_modules/@myapp/ui/components/SvgIcon.js`:

[image]

What am I missing?

UPDATE: I updated it with an example of a component fully converted to Typescript